# Passing json object as argument to render() in jinja2 python

Tags: python, jinja2

I trying to create a json object and pass that object to `template.render(JSONObj)`, but there is some error saying

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am also facing the same prob. Please somebody help us..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to give that "JSONObj" object a key value. The template recieves a dictionary with objects and values to render inside it. So, try using this:

```
template.render(jsonobj=JSONObj)
```

Then, in your template, you can use this object this way:

```
{{jsonobj.some_key_inside_json_object}}
```

This `jsonobj` is a name that identifies your "JSONObj" object inside the template's arguments.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks you so much for help.. I will try update you.. thank u so much once again..

Comment: Thank you very much for your ans. It is working fine.. thank u so much.

Comment: I have accepted ur ans.. thanks again..since when ur using JINJA2?? I am just starting my website in this, is this k to continue..??

Comment: I don't use Jinja. I use django (in this particular case, django templates) but they have a lot in common. I've never read which are the biggest differences between them, so i can't tell you which is the best. I think the best is the best that suits you. When you feel it's limiting your coding, it's time to move on, but if not, continue using what you like the most...